# How to reuse page queries in custom gutenberg blocks or shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'd like to solve this problem, but not sure if it's even possible...

Say I've got a page which on header shows some terms, so I start retrieving them:

```
  $children_terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent' => $related_product_term->term_id
  ));
```

Great. Then I start post_content output, which is plain gutenberg blocks.

In the middle of the page contents from gutenberg, I would need to show again the above terms, like cards with thumb and title. I can do it via shortcode or custom block, but the problem is that at this point, I'm going to repeat the above query, which I already did in page template.

Is there a way to simply reuse `$children_terms` on the custom block or shortcode?

Or, even more impossible: is there a way to split gutenberg output in 2 pieces, so that I can place standard 'manual' code in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way to pass page (`$children_terms`, see above) variables to a shortcode from gutenberg. But I solved with an 'empty' (where I mean: with no custom fields) acf block and passing `$children_terms` from the page template with `set_query_var`, a wordpress api function.